# dotnet restore and clear don't fix dependency issue in vscode

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

Two of my vscode C# aspnetcore projects are showing different versions of a third party model and I have manually changed the .csproj to point to the correct nuget package version.  I have run the following commands:

- nuget locals all -clear
- nuget restore

Yet when I Go To Definition on the model, it's still showing the older version. What gives?

Comment: Does the old DLL still exist? Check your project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to close and reopen VS Code before you see updated nuget code when viewing definitions (F12).  So frustrating.